# How to grab random images from a site using IMPORTXML on Google Sheets?

Tags: image, random, google-sheets-formula

I want to grab random images from a site using [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) on Google Sheets. This is currently my code:

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCAT("https://unsplash.com/s/photos/", query(SPLIT(AA2, ">"), "SELECT Col2")), "(//img)[9]/@src")
```

At the moment, it only grabs the 9th picture with this code: `"(//img)[9]/@src"`. How can I make it so it grabs images randomly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know how many images are there. For example if you have 10 images, you can replace

```
"(//img)[9]/@src"
```

with

```
"(//img)["&randbetween(1,10)&"]/@src"
```

This puts a random number between 1 and 10 in your code.

If you don't know, you should run IMPORTXML to list all the images and then wrap it with ROWS() formula to get this number.

```
"(//img)["&randbetween(1,ROWS(IMPORTXML(your list of images)))&"]/@src"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried, but it's showing ERROR with this note "This function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()"

Any idea what might be wrong? This is the new code at the moment `=IMPORTXML(CONCAT("https://unsplash.com/s/photos/", query(SPLIT(AA2, ">"), "SELECT Col2")),"(//img)["&randbetween(1,20)&"]/@src")`

Comment: Interesting. Never seen this error message. How about trying =Index(IMPORTXML_WITH_LIST_OF_ALL_IMAGES,randbetween(1,10),1) - this should generate a list and then take a random row from it.